# How to use allow deny rules with userId when you have implemented your own user login/logout?

Tags: meteor

I've implemented my own user login and logout system by just setting a session variable and checking it in my main template so I will display a login screen if not logged in and display the app if I am logged in (this is typically how I did things with PHP).

I did this instead of using any of the built in user account systems because I needed to implement my own login password check to a legacy web service.

Because of this, it seems I'm running into trouble now because things like allow/deny rules for my file uploads don't seem to have the userId:

```
download: function (userId, doc) {
            console.log("userId ", userId);
        return true;
    }
```

This prints : **userId null**

So, I'm unable to implement any logic here based upon whether the user is logged in or not.

So, is there a way for me to tell the meteor accounts system what my userId is when I perform my custom login?  --- which I presume would then make it available here in the download allow/deny rule?

EDIT: I've had to implement a custom login handler with Accounts.registerLoginHandler.  Doing this caused the meteor system to set the userId in the built in accounts system, which allowed it to be passed into the allow/deny functions... but my question still stands.  I would like to know if there is a way to alternately provide some information (say, the values of a session variable) to these allow/deny rules instead of being limited to using the built in accounts system.

Comment: I realize that you are trying to completely bypass the Accounts system, however you will also run into issues with packages in Atmosphere.  The best bet is to simply accept that you will need Accounts, and look at how the third party logins are handled (Like accounts-meetup).  [See this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages)

Comment: Yes @MrMowgli I agree... per my edit, I have since discovered the registerLoginHandler method, which was very helpful, as I could implement my own login methods yet still keep the meteor Accounts system intact.  This has helped in many ways to just use the standard Accounts system... it is just unfamiliar from a PHP environment background, where you would just set a session variable yourself to indicate logged in status...